# ( C# ) Xamarin.android Fragment Webview not displaying anything

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

in one of the fragments in my multi-tabbed app, I have a webview which won't display anything. I probably just have the code wrong, so here's the axml file (fragment1.axml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the cs file (fragment1.cs):

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace TabsApp.Fragments
{
    public class Fragment1 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment1 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag1 = new Fragment1 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag1;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);

            WebView webView = v.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);

            webView.LoadUrl("https://google.com");

            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, null);
        }
    }
}
```

other things ( like text views ) work fine so there is nothing wrong with any other part of the app and the (INTERNET) permission has been enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);

    WebView webView = v.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);

    webView.LoadUrl("https://google.com");

    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, null);
}
```

Can you not spot what is wrong with it?

You inflate a `View` `v`, which you find your `WebView` in and do you stuff. However, on the last line where you return. You inflate it again, disregarding anything else you've done in that method. Just return `v`.

Answer (score 0):

return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, null); This Line of code cause problem because your are inflating view again,which you already inflated 
here: **View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);**

So **only return v;** in place of

**return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, null);**